# mmap address at later point of time with only the address on which Im doing mmap

Tags: linux, unix, mmap

I have a program where at the start I'm creating a mmap based on addresses in some segments.

But I'm not storing the mmap value.

Is there any way possible to get mmap address based on the addresses that I'm using to create it.

I know there is a way to store the mmap addresses that I had created along with the address I'm passing to it. But I'm asking a different question.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can, you should store the `mmap` address. Retrieving it afterwards seems more complicated to do than is necessary. It's like not storing the result of `malloc` and trying to find it later on. Maybe tell us why you can't store the address.

Comment: I know I can do storing of mmap values. But just asking if there is any possible way to do it using any library/system calls.